# Table class to fill array structure with values

Tags: beginner, object-oriented, ruby, unit-testing

The code creates a table and adds rows and columns.

- Does it make sense to write the code like this?
- Would you design it differently?
- Is there a better OOP approach to this?

```
class Table
  attr_reader :grid

  def initialize(rows: , columns:)
    @grid = construct(rows, columns)
  end

  def construct(rows, columns)
    raise 'arguments must be arrays' unless rows.is_a?(Array) && columns.is_a?(Array)
    table = []
    rows = [] if rows.nil?
    rows.each do |row|
      table << columns.map do |c| c end
    end
    table
  end
end
```

Here are the specs which describe what it is doing:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require_relative '..\test'

RSpec.describe Table do 

  it 'is empty' do
    table = Table.new(rows: [], columns: [])
    expect(table.grid).to eq []
  end

  it 'raises if no array is given' do
    expect { 
      Table.new(rows: [], columns: 1) }.to raise_error RuntimeError
    expect { 
      Table.new(rows: 1, columns:[]) }.to raise_error RuntimeError
  end

  it 'has several rows and columns' do
    row = double('row')
    column = double('column')
    col = Column.new.value = 14
    table = Table.new(rows: [1, 3, 3], columns: [1, col])
    expect(table.grid).to eq [
      [1, 2], 
      [1, 2], 
      [1, 2]
    ]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

### Refactored Code

This is a possible way to refactor the code to meet the style guidelines of [Ruby](https://rubystyle.guide/) using [Rubocop](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop).

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

# A simple table with rows and cols
class Table
  attr_reader :grid

  def initialize(rows:, columns:)
    @grid = construct(rows, columns)
  end

  def construct(rows, columns)
    unless rows.is_a?(Array) && columns.is_a?(Array)
      raise 'arguments must be arrays'
    end

    table = []
    rows = [] if rows.nil?
    rows.each do |_row|
      table << columns.map { |c| c }
    end
    table
  end
end
```

---

### Style Considerations

A guard clause should be appended wih an empty line. Also, since the line is over 80 characters, split it up in multi-line.

> ```
> raise 'arguments must be arrays' unless rows.is_a?(Array) && columns.is_a?(Array)
> table = []
> ```

```
unless rows.is_a?(Array) && columns.is_a?(Array)
  raise 'arguments must be arrays'
end

table = []
```

You have an unused block argument `row` and the map should be rewritten using `{..}`.

> ```
> rows.each do |row|
>   table << columns.map do |c| c end
> end
> ```

```
rows.each do |_row|
  table << columns.map { |c| c }
end
```

---

### General Guidelines and Conventions

The tool also complained about the following guidelines.

- use 2 instead of 4 white spaces for indentation
- remove any trailing white space
- remove space before comma
- add a frozen string literal comment [justification](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/FrozenStringLiteralComment)
- add top level class documentation comment